# Default array parameter is not printing all values within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, parameter-passing

I am passing default array parameter within JavaScript as follows:

```
<script>
    function addArray(a = [101]) {
        document.write('A: ' + a[0] + '<br>');
        document.write('B: ' + a + '<br>');
        document.write('C: ' + c + '<br>');
    }

    addArray([110]);
</script>
```

### Output:

```
A: 110
B: 110
```

The output is not printing values for `C`.
Also, `A` and `B` are showing the same values.
Need some help to understand this unusual behavior of passing array as default parameter.

Comment: There is no variable c. Also a[0] and a are basically an array of size 1 which print out similar values.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a reference error because c doesn't exist in that scope. 
At least in this piece of code.
I don't write this reply like a comment because I don't have points needed for it.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the c into an a.
The variable a[0] is the same like a in this case.

Comment: why `C` is not showing as undefined. Can you provide more explanation?